# How to change datasource in kendo listview

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, listview, kendo-ui

This is the method I have used to bind remote data to ListView based on the date.

```
function getListData(date) { 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: wcfurl + "getList",
        data: '{"date":"' + date + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item1) {
                listds = item1;                                                
            });                    
            $("#listview").kendoListView({                        
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: JSON.parse(listds)                                      
                }),                        
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                altTemplate: kendo.template($("#altTemplate").html()),
                selectable: true,
                change: function () {
                    var index = this.select().index(), dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[index];
                    alert("id: " + dataItem.id + ", table: " + dataItem.tableno);
                }
            });                   
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error : " + result);
        }
    }); 
}
```

From following method I pass the date to this `[getListData(date)]` method.

```
function initCalander() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function () {
            var today = new Date(),
            events = [+new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 10),
             +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 20)];
            $(".calendar").kendoCalendar({
                value: today,
                dates: events,
                change: function () {
                    var d = kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd');
                    getListData(d);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This works perfectly initially, But if I change the date the list rebinds with current data, till now ok, the problem is, in `change` of listview the alert message appears two times, on first it displays old data, and second time only it displays current data.

I don't know what is the problem. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: @LarsHöppner Sorry friend, Now I have my service in locolhost only. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 function initCalander() {
        $.ajax({
              ..
              var d = kendo.toString(new Date(result.Value), 'd');
              getListData(d);
              ..
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the ListView multiple times, this is not something that I would recommend.

Instead you can initialize  the ListView and Calendar only once - when the DOM ready event is triggered and from then on you  can use the methods of the dataSource such as **[dataSource.data](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-data)** to set the underlying collection.

Comment: I am new to this, Can you explain little bit more, `How can I initialize it once and change the data?`